# Flutter - _CastError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I stored a list of Map data in firestore database. But when I tried to fetch the data to a variable of type List<Map<String, dynamic>>, it shows the error "_CastError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast)".

Here is the code,

```
// code to fetch objects list from database
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getUserObjects() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> userInfo = await getUserInfo();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> userObjects = userInfo['objects'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = [];
    for(var i=0; i<userObjects.length; i++) {
      var docInfo = await DatabaseMethods().getDocumentInfo(findCollectionName(userObjects[i]['objectType']), userObjects[i]['docId']) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      result.add({'icon': findIcon(userObjects[i]['objectType']), 'objectName' : docInfo['objectName'], 'docId' : userObjects[i]['docId']});
    }
    return result;
  }


Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserInfo() async {
    var user = await FirebaseAuthentication().getCurrentUser();
    Map<String, dynamic> userInfo = await DatabaseMethods().getuserFromDB(user.uid);
    if(userInfo['objects'] == null) {
      userInfo.addAll({'objects' : []});
    }
    return userInfo;
  }

final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
    return auth.currentUser!;
  }

// code to add an object to object list in collection 'user'

Future<void> updateUserObjectList(Map<String, dynamic> object) async {
    var user = await FirebaseAuthentication().getCurrentUser();
    var userId = user.uid;
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId)
      .update({'objects' : FieldValue.arrayUnion([object])});
  }
```

The data stored in the database will look like the below image with the following changes,

1. replace 'quotes' with 'objects'
2. replace 'auther' with 'objectType'
3. replace 'quote' with 'docId'
4. replace 'user' with 'users'

[image]

Can someone say where the error happened. Code gives the error in the line "List<Map<String, dynamic>> userObjects = userInfo['objects'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;"  in getUserObjects method

Comment: The database uses `user`, but the coder `'users'`. Also, `getUserInfo()` is not shown.

Comment: I have updated the code with getUserInfo() method. Also the actual collection name is 'users'

Comment: Can you share the code for the `getUserFromDB()` function?

Comment: It was a mistake in the document id. I was using userid+datetime but I forgot to add datetime in the call. I solved the issue. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @gireesh Since you solved the cause of this issue, you should convert your comment into a separate answer for this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the OP's solution into an answer for this question, this specific issue was caused by sending an incorrect `document.id` in the fetch call.

Using the correct document ID (`user.id + datetime` for the OP's case) solved the problem.